# unattended-upgrades Download-Upgradeable-Packages setting

Tags: linux, debian, automatic-update

I have previously setup unattended-upgrades on Ubuntu servers using [the official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html).

I am now trying to setup the same on a Debian/Raspbian system; [that guide is here](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades).

My question is only about the `20auto-upgrades` file.

The Ubuntu guide says that it should contain:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

But the Debian guide has only the first and the last line. I understand the AutocleanInterval.

What does the Download-Upgradeable-Packages do? More importantly: Why does the Debian guide not need this?

Answer (score 0):

Little further down on the Debian documentation it says:

```
// Do "apt-get upgrade --download-only" every n-days (0=disable)
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
```

And from `man apt-get`:

```
-d, --download-only
       Download only; package files are only retrieved, not unpacked or installed.
```

I assume this means that updatable packages will be downloaded separate from when the actual upgrade runs.